# Keras: Loading model built with CuDNNLSTM on host without GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I trained a keras model that uses `CuDNNLSTM` cells, and now wish to load the model on a host device that lacks a GPU. Because `CuDNNLSTM` cells require a GPU, though, the loading process bombs out, throwing:

> No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' with these attrs.

Is there some backdoor that will allow me to load the model on a host without a GPU? Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: perhaps you can replace it with an LSTM and load the weights and run inference?

Comment: @kvish is there a way to mutate the result of myModel.save() before loading the model? Do I just parse the model as an h5 object or is there a nicer API?

Comment: you could parse the model as a json. It would not save the weights, just the architecture. You could save the weights alone using save_weights() function and then load weights by using load_weights().
This [FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) gives a good overview of the options available.
Probably you can parse a LSTM architecture to json then load the json, then the weights?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: I am using Keras 2.2.4 and TensorFlow 1.12.0.
I was able to solve the issue with the following steps:

1) Train the model with CudnnLSTM and save the model (model_GPU.json) and the weights (*.h5).

2) Define the same model changing CudnnLSTM for LSTM, this must be done in a system/computer with no GPU, and then you can save the model (model_CPU.json).

2*) In the LSTM cell set activation='tanh',recurrent_activation='sigmoid'. Since these are the default ones in CudnnLSTM.

3) Then you can load model_CPU.json with the weights trained with CudnnLSTM.

Specifically, I used the following

**CPU:**

```
from keras.layers import LSTM

Bidirectional(LSTM(hidden_units_LSTM, return_sequences=True,activation='tanh',recurrent_activation='sigmoid'))(output)
```

**GPU:**

```
from keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM

Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(hidden_units_LSTM, return_sequences=True))(output)
```

Comment: Amen, I ended up doing the same but never looped back to post an answer. Thanks for writing out the steps!